# Convert AWS CloudFormation S3 resources to Terraform resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I want to convert AWS S3 resources form cloudformation template to terraform template.
But No existing data loss/data changes should be there to the S3 storage result from the transition. 
Please suggest some idea, how we can avoid S3 bucket data loss or data change issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terraform import` to achieve this.  Here's a short example of importing an S3 bucket:

1. Create your terraform definition for the bucket.  You can leave all attributes empty.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
}
```

2. run `terraform init` to enable providers
3. run `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket <name-of-existing-bucket>`

Now the bucket will be in the Terraform state file and can be managed with Terraform.  Any changes to the Terraform file can now be applied to the existing bucket.